# Android Studio: Gradle Script faild to sync with the error message - "Failed to resolve: com"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

If I try to sync my app in Android Studio I get the follwing error message:

```
Failed to resolve: com
Show in File
```

If I click on "Show in File" my build.gradle opens and my cursor is on the first line.
This is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.vertretungsplan"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.a ndroid.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20'
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.13'
    implementation 'com.turki-alkhateeb:materialcolorpicker:1.0.7'
}
```

I hope somebody can help me.
Thanks you very much!

Comment: That's the mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Great, added it as the answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the added space in this line:

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.a ndroid.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
```